# Web Page which adds 3 letters to a string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a webpage where the user inputs a nine digit number and the output has the letters ABC added to the beginning.  Eg. input:'123456789' output:ABC123456789

Here is my code (pieced together from samples on the web) but there is no output:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>Add ABC</TITLE>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">

function convert() {

    var inp = document.conv.inpt.value 
    outp = "ABC" + inp
    document.conv.newname.value = outp
  }
}
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FORM ACTION="#" NAME="conv">
Input:<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="inpt" SIZE=40>
<BR><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Enter Name" ONCLICK="convert()">
<BR><BR>
Output:<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="newname" SIZE=40 DISABLED>
</FORM>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: jsfiddle is your friend:  http://jsfiddle.net/zuFuS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok except that you have an extra `}` at the end, causing a syntax error. The error console is your friend--it will alert you to the existence of errors such as this (or an IDE, if you are using one to write your code).

Also, FYI, it is a good idea to put `var` in front of all variables, including `outp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert() {

var inp = document.getElementsByName('inp')[0].value 
outp = "ABC" + inp
document.getElementsByName('newname')[0].value = outp
}
```

Extra brace. And above seems easy method for me.

Answer (score 0):

remove extra `}`

```
function convert() {
    var inp = document.conv.inpt.value
    outp = "ABC" + inp
    document.conv.newname.value = outp
}
```

use double quotes to define html

```
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="inpt" SIZE=40>
    to
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="inpt" SIZE="40">
```